# Obtener un input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi pregunta es algo sencilla:

¿Es posible obtener un input por su id y su name?

Es decir, tengo dos inputs:

```
<input id="uno" name="a"/>

<input id="dos" name="a"/>

<input id="uno" name="b"/>

<input id="dos" name="b"/>
```

Pero quiero enviar un value al segundo input, solo a ese.

Yo se que un input debe tener un id, pero resulta que tengo un generador de formularios y puede suceder que el cliente en algún momento se le olvide cambiar el id del input y este se genera automáticamente, ocasionando que pueda repetirse.

Comment: Buen día, qué haz intentado hacer?

Comment: Tienes que añadir a tu pregunta lo que ha realizado hasta ahora a partir de allí te ayudaran, comparte tu html y js.

Comment: al momento lo que he intentado es digamos, que obviamente es de formularios diferentes, pero digamos que en el formulario 5 se me repite el id, se envia el value a id del input anterior borrandome el dato anterior

Comment: El `id` debe ser único si o si, siempre, El id es un identificador del cliente, es decir se usa en el navegador y principalmente en javascript, aunque puedes obtener un elemento de otras maneras sin ocupar el `id`. El `name` se usa del lado del servidor, cuando se envían los datos en un formulario, puede repetirse si se usan en forma de array, ej: `nombre[]` con el sufijo `[]` para algunos servidores, en otros es necesario colocar el índice `nombre[1]`

Comment: como dice @Yussef tienes un error de sintaxy en tu html ... no pueden existir elementos con id duplicados .

Comment: El "name" es el valor que vas a recibir en el lado del server. Mala idea lo que estás haciendo, utiliza `id` de valor único y del mismo modo, `name` de valor único.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues si estas usando *JQuery* como dice tu etiqueta es sencillo utilizando los selectores con los que cuenta `$("")`, solo debes usar lo siguiente:

Para obtener el input por el *id*:

```
const input = $('#id');
```

Para obtenerlo por la clase:

```
const input = $('.class');
```

Para obtenerlo mediante un atributo:

```
const input = $('input[attribute="value"]');
```

En tu caso para obtenerlo por dos atributos (id, nombre):

```
const input = $('input[id="idInput"][name="nombreInput"]');
```

Puedes ver más información sobre selectores para Jquery en https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```js
function mostrarValor() {
  const inputUno = $('#uno');
  console.log('Input uno:', inputUno.val());

  const inputDos = $('input[id="dos"][name="a"]');
  console.log('Input dos:', inputDos.val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="uno" name="a" /><br>
<input id="dos" name="a" /><br>

<button onclick='mostrarValor()'>Mostrar valores</button>
```

Pero como bien te dicen en los comentarios el *id* debe ser único, es muy mala práctica que pase lo que mencionas (que el mismo *id* pueda existir en varios componentes incluso cuando es generado automáticamente).

Comment: muchas gracias, muy amable

Answer (score 1):

Con el método [**`querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) puedes obtener múltiples atributos, en este caso obtendremos al **`id`** y al **`name`** del segundo *input*. De ésta forma tendremos únicamente al segundo *input* ya que es el único quien lleva ese **`id`** junto con ese **`name`**, sería de esta forma:

```js
document.querySelector('input[id="dos"][name="a"]').value = "valor";
```

```html
<input id="uno" name="a"/><br>
<input id="dos" name="a"/><br>
<input id="uno" name="b"/><br>
<input id="dos" name="b"/><br>
```

También, recuerda que Los **`id`** son los identificadores de cada uno de los elementos, éstos siempre van a ser **únicos** y no se deben repetir en más de un elemento, para ello podrías trabajar con clases, véase más **[aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)**.

Comment: este metodo tambien me funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: Claro, es una solución que motiva la mala práctica (`id` duplicado).

Comment: @mauriCioContreras pero se lo estoy diciendo justo debajo en mi respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

puede hacerlo asi:

```js
//seleccionamos el input con name b y id dos
let input1 = document.querySelector("input[name='b']#dos");
console.log(input1);
// a lo inverso
let input2 = document.querySelector("input#dos[name='a']");
console.log(input2);
```

```css
div #dos {
 border-color:blue;
 color:blue;
}

div#dos {
 border-color:red;
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<input id="uno" name="a"/> <br>
<input id="dos" name="a"/> <br>
<input id="uno" name="b"/> <br>
<input id="dos" name="b"/> <br>

<div id="dos">padre <span id="dos"> hijo</span></div>
<div id="dos">padre <span id="dos"> hijo</span></div>
```

## **NOTA**

para jquery solo es remplazar **document.querySelector** por **$**

si se coloca el selector todo junto sin espacio hace referencia al elemento actual ejemplo: **rojo**

si se agrega un espacio hace referencia los hijos ejemplo: **azul**

se ilustro con un css para mayor compresion

Answer (score -2):

puedes probar con

> var valor = document.getElementById("id del input").value

asío recogeras el valor del input que tenga el mismo id que el que tu le escribes

si únicamente quieres el input para más adelante conseguir el valor o hacer otra cosa haces simplemente esta línea

```
document.getElementById("id del input")
```

Comment: esto no responde lo que el OP está solicitando. verifica nuevamente la duda que presenta el usuario.